# ios swift - issues with keyboard (cover up textfield, etc..) and some other widgets

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm an android guy and have recently started to learn swift.

I have went through the tutorial about the structure of swift, but what's really giving me headache now is the UI widgets

1. keyboard covers up textfield. how can I make it so view would get pushed up if textfield is covered but does nothing when textfield is visible. the example I found [here](http://www.buildsucceeded.com/2014/swift-move-uitextfield-so-keyboard-does-not-hide-it-ios-8-xcode-6-swift/) would push the view up or down to be exactly right above the keyboard, but pushing the view down isn't what I want.
2. how can I have the error icon on the right within the textfield like this? and also how to add an additional row of navigation right above the keyboard to allow user go backward/forward and Done
   [image]
3. I found a Date Picker in Object library, but it takes a lot of space. What I want is like the screenshot below. it pushes the view up when user click on something then disappear when done. and also the same question on how to have the additional nav bar right on the top of keyboard
   [image]
4. I don't know if it's going to be the same thing as Date Picker. I also want a list show up at the bottom when event is triggered.

Can someone please please help me? or direct me to the right article. I found myself having really hard time on UI when coding in swift :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix:
You can use [this](https://github.com/ttippin84/VBResponsiveTextFieldViewController), which is a subclass of ViewController that won't let UITextFields be hidden by the keyboard. (more details on link)

Hard way: Implement by yourself a method which respond when keyboard is show, get its height and textfield location, then move view of viewController. And another method to respond when keyboard is dismiss to restore view of viewController.

**Edit:**
For textFields, its better put image right of textfield, or maybe upon textField (but its ugly when there is text behind). That bar is a accessory view and you can use in any textField, even when you’re using DatePicker or PickerView.

For Datepicker, [here](http://www.codebuddies.de/2015/03/06/show-uidatepicker-on-uitextfield-tap-in-swift/) there is a simple way.

For Accessory view:

Swift code

```
//TODO:First tag all textFields in your view, starting by 1.

//In your viewController
var textFields:[UITextField]? = nil //Class attribute
var activeTextField:UITextField? = nil //Class attribute

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    textFields = [UITextField]()
    searchTextFields(self.view)
    setAccessoryView()
}

//MARK: Helper functions
//Search for all textFields in your view (and subviews), if tag is greater than 0, connect delegate and append to ‘textFields’ array.
func searchTextFields(_view: UIView) {
    for subView in _view.subviews {
        if subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField) {
            let textField = subView as UITextField
            if textField.tag > 0 {
                textField.delegate = self
                textFields?.append(subView as UITextField)
            }
        } else if subView.isKindOfClass(UIView) {
            searchTextFields(subView as UIView)
        }
    }
}

func setAccessoryView() {
    if textFields != nil {
        //Create buttons
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let ok = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "okButtonAction")
        //TODO: Place your own images
        let next = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "setaDireita"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "nextButton")
        let previous = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "setaEsquerda"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "previousButton")

        //Order buttons
        let itensToolbar = NSMutableArray(array: [previous, next, space, ok])

        //Create toolbar
        let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 0))
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolbar.items = itensToolbar
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        //Set toolbar
        for textField in textFields! {
            textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        }
    }
}

//MARK: Actions AccessoryView
func okButtonAction() {
    //You can do whatever you want
    self.activeTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
}

func nextButton() {
    if activeTextField?.tag != textFields?.last?.tag {
        textFields?[activeTextField!.tag].becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

func previousButton() {
    if activeTextField?.tag != textFields?.first?.tag {
        textFields?[activeTextField!.tag - 2].becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = textField
    let toolbar = textField.inputAccessoryView as UIToolbar
    if textField.tag == textFields?.first?.tag {
        (toolbar.items?[0] as UIBarButtonItem).enabled = false
        (toolbar.items?[1] as UIBarButtonItem).enabled = true
    } else if textField.tag == textFields?.last?.tag {
        (toolbar.items?[0] as UIBarButtonItem).enabled = true
        (toolbar.items?[1] as UIBarButtonItem).enabled = false
    } else {
        (toolbar.items?[0] as UIBarButtonItem).enabled = true
        (toolbar.items?[1] as UIBarButtonItem).enabled = true
    }
}
```

Hope helps you.

Comment: that's exactly the same as what I found in my question. the viewcontroller would move the entire view down even when there is enough space

Comment: That's easy. On ResponsiveTextFieldViewController, line 71 replace with this `if self.keyboardFrame.intersects(self.activeTextField!.frame) { self.arrangeViewOffsetFromKeyboard() }`, line 135 replace whit this `if self.keyboardFrame.intersects(self.activeTextField!.frame) { self.arrangeViewOffsetFromKeyboard() } else { returnViewToInitialFrame() }`. This class will not help you if textField is not in main view. If you want I have my own implementation of this class, that resolve this issue.

Comment: oh thanks! i found the solution in that tutorial from the comments below. do you know anything about error message within the textfield and the nav above keyboard?

Comment: that is sooo awesome!! let me try it tomorrow. I've been searching around for a dropdown or spinner(like in android) type of widget. couldnt find any, so i ended up with using a tableview to display a list of options. it looks ugly but since i know that is called `PickerView` now, i know what to google. thanks!